# parsing url using re.match().groups() in python

Tags: python, regex, error-handling

Apologies in advance if this question seems quite basic.

**Given**:

Apache HTTP Access Log file as follows:

```
sample_apache_access_log_line = '- - [01/Feb/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /aikakausi/binding/1145113/image/14 HTTP/1.1" 200 658925 "http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/binding/1145113?page=14&term=HOIKKA" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-J320FN Build/LMY47V; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/MESSENGER;FBAV/100.0.0.29.61;]" 569'
```

**Goal**:

I extract information with the following pattern:

```
CUSTOM_LOG_PATTERN = '- - \[.*?\] "(.*)" (\d{3}) (.*) "([^\"]+)" "(.*?)" (.*)'    
matched_line = re.match(ACCESS_LOG_PATTERN, sample_apache_access_log_line)
print (matched_line)
l = matched_line.groups() # WORKS OK
```

which I then dump all info into a list for further processing:

```
cleaned_lines = []
cleaned_lines.append({
                "timestamp":            l[0],
                "client_request_line":  l[1],
                "status":               l[2],
                "bytes_sent":           l[3],
                "referer":              l[4],
                "user_agent":           l[5],
                "session_id":           l[6],
})
```

**Problem**:

There exists sometime some lines with broken url (referer) (starting with `http://192.168.8.1/`) similar to:

```
sample_apache_access_log_line = '- - [01/Feb/2017:12:34:51 +0200] "GET /aikakausi/binding/499213?page=55 HTTP/1.1" 401 1612 "http://192.168.8.1/html/home.html?url&address=http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/binding/499213?page=55" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" 1995'
```

which I would like to manipulate them using regex to say always start with `http://LETTERS` , that is why I changed my code to:

```
CUSTOM_LOG_PATTERN = '- - \[.*?\] "(http://[a-zA-Z].*)" (\d{3}) (.*) "([^\"]+)" "(.*?)" (.*)' 
                                    <<<<<PROBLEM>>>>>
matched_line = re.match(CUSTOM_LOG_PATTERN, sample_apache_access_log_line)
print (matched_line)
l = matched_line.groups() # ERROR
print(l)
```

But then here it comes the error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-88-c7a93cfbce61> in <module>
      4 matched_line = re.match(CUSTOM_LOG_PATTERN, sample_apache_access_log_line)
      5 print (matched_line)
----> 6 l = matched_line.groups()
      7 print(l)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong between for `re.match().groups()`?

Comment: Clearly. Your second regex doesn't match. We don't know how you came up with that or why you hoped it would match; it is quite substantially different from your first attempt. What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Having `.*` in multiple places also threatens to throw you into catastrophic backtracking. You probably mean something like `[^"]*` but we can't read your mind.

Comment: What do you need to capture? Please edit the question.

Comment: appologies for confusion, I updated my question. the problem is I want to extract referer links startarting from `http://LETTERS` in one line.

Comment: Maybe just `re.findall(r'http://[^"]*', sample_apache_access_log_line)`?

Comment: It still gives the same error for `.group()` to generate tuples. I need to manipulate the pattern in `re.match()` to group all the lines and extract information into a dict for further application!

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall()` then `re.split()`.

```
pattern = '(http://\D.*)'                        #matches any non-digits after 'http://'
url_start = re.findall(pattern, log_file_string) #get the starting point of url
url = re.split("\s", url_start)                  #to get the url alone by 
                                                 #splitting on whitespace

url = url[0]
```

You may need to use `str.strip()` to remove any remaining special characters enclosing the url.

If you must use `re.match()` try simplifying the pattern.

```
pattern = '(.*)"(http://\D.*)"(.*)'
url_start = re.match(pattern, log_file_string)
url_string = url_start.group(2)
url = re.split("\s", url_string)
url = url[0].strip('"')
```

Using `Match.groups()` returns a tuple. Used `Match.group()` above. Try:

```
pattern = '(.*)"(http://\D.*)"[^\"]'
url_start = re.match(pattern, log_file_string)
url = url_start.groups(2)
url = url[1]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use this pattern inside `re.match()` ? I need to use `.group()` so `.split()` option does not work in my case! if I add  `CUSTOM_LOG_PATTERN = '- - \[(.*?)\] "(http://\D.*)" (\d{3}) (.*) "([^\"]+)" "(.*?)" (.*)'`, I still get the None error in re.match()

Comment: Updated answer with re.match()

Comment: I am still getting the same error due to `None`! what was the `log_file_string` you used to test this code?

Comment: Updated. I tested with the strings provided. Alternatively, if it's your Apache server you can adjust how the logfile is formatted so that it is easier to parse. [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)

Answer (score 0):

if url is all you need you can just use `split()`

```
sample_apache_access_log_line = [

'- - [01/Feb/2017:12:34:51 +0200] "GET /aikakausi/binding/499213?page=55 HTTP/1.1" 401 1612 "http://192.168.8.1/html/home.html?url&address=http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/binding/499213?page=55" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" 1995', 
'- - [01/Feb/2017:12:34:53 +0200] "GET /aikakausi/binding/641892?term=PETSAMON&term=Petsamon&page=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 3162 "http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/search?query=petsamo&requireAllKeywords=true&fuzzy=false&hasIllustrations=false&startDate=1918-12-30&endDate=1920-12-30&orderBy=RELEVANCE&pages=&page=5" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0" 418'
]


for i in sample_apache_access_log_line:
    if 'address=' in i:
        print(i.split('"')[3].split('address=')[1])
    else:
        print(i.split('"')[3])

# http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/binding/499213?page=55
# http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/search?query=petsamo&requireAllKeywords=true&fuzzy=false&hasIllustrations=false&startDate=1918-12-30&endDate=1920-12-30&orderBy=RELEVANCE&pages=&page=5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question, I need more generic pattern which works with regex for variety of lines with such broken url which I have in one line!

Comment: I've reread it , I guess you get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` because that huge long regex doesn't work, it returns `None` cuz there is some mistake inside it. And as I can get it so far your problem in general doesn't need using regex at all, you can salve it with `split()` easily. All you need to do is to detect texts with broken url and apply to it this `.split('"')[3].split('=')[1]`

Comment: Your are right! I do not know the correct pattern to use in `re.match()` and `.groups()` returns `None`

But I should get this results instead: `http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/binding/499213?page=55` your answer does not return it

Comment: no it changes from link to link

Comment: I comes from log file, this is another sample in my `file.log`:  `- - [01/Feb/2017:12:34:53 +0200] "GET /aikakausi/binding/641892?term=PETSAMON&term=Petsamon&page=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 3162 "http://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/aikakausi/search?query=petsamo&requireAllKeywords=true&fuzzy=false&hasIllustrations=false&startDate=1918-12-30&endDate=1920-12-30&orderBy=RELEVANCE&pages=&page=5" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0" 418`

Comment: I've edited my answer for working with both broken url and non-broken url, check it.